# ¿Por qué si pido 5 valores, solo me imprime 4 con getline?

Tags: c++

Regreso a su sabiduría nuevamente.
El tema es este, mi código:

```
void quickSortASC(char art[][60], int cuentas);
void quickSortAS(char art[][60], int izq, int der);

void ascendente() {
    int i;
    int canciones;
    int k = 1;
    char str[60][60];
    cout << "Introduce el numero de canciones (Max. 60)\n ->  ";
    cin >> canciones;
    cout << "Introduce las " <<canciones<< " canciones:\n";
    for (i = -1; i < canciones; i++) {
        cin.getline(str[i], 60, '\n');
    }

    quickSortASC(str, canciones);

    cout << "\nLas canciones ordenadas de forma ascendente son:  \n";
    for (i = 0; i < canciones; i++) {
        cout << k << ":";
        printf("%s ",str[i]);
        printf("\n");
        k++;
    }
}
```

Y:

```
void quickSortDEC(char art[][60], int cuentas);
void quickSortDE(char art[][60], int izq, int der);
void descendente() {
    int i;
    int canciones;
    int k = 1;
    char str[60][60];
    cout << "Introduce el numero de canciones (Max. 60)\n ->  ";
    cin >> canciones;
    cout << "Introduce las " << canciones << " canciones:\n";
    for (i = 0; i < canciones; i++) {
        cin.getline(str[i], 50, '\n');
}

    quickSortDEC(str, canciones);

    cout << "\nLas canciones ordenadas de forma Descendente son:  \n";
    for (i = 0; i < canciones; i++) {
        cout << k << ":";
        printf("%s", str[i]);
        printf("\n");
        k++;
    }
}
void quickSortDEC(char art[][60], int cuentas)
{
    quickSortDE(art, 0, cuentas - 1);
}

void quickSortDE(char art[][60], int izq, int der)
{
    int i, j;
    char* x;
    char temp[60];

    i = izq;
    j = der;
    x = art[(izq + der) / 2];

    do {
        while ((strcmp(art[i], x) > 0) && (i < der)) {
            i++;
    }
        while ((strcmp(art[j], x) < 0) && (j > izq)) {
            j--;
        }
        if (i <= j) {
            strcpy_s(temp, art[i]);
            strcpy_s(art[i], art[j]);
            strcpy_s(art[j], temp);
            i++;
            j--;
        }
    } while (i <= j);

    if (izq < j) {
        quickSortDE(art, izq, j);
    }
    if (i < der) {
        quickSortDE(art, i, der);
    }
}
```

> Para ascendente es similar al descendente, solo cambiando lo <,>.
>
> El tema es que en el numero de canciones le pongo "5" y me imprime un
> espacio vacio, 2,3,4,5. Ejemplo: ERA DADO CAMA BEBE AVE

```
Me lo ordena como;
1:;
2: AVE;
3: BEBE;
4: CAMA;
5: DADO;
```

> En void ascendente() lo arregle poniendo -1, pero sé que no es
> correcto. El tema es que necesito que me acepte espacios, si pongo
> simplemente:

```
cin(canciones);
```

> si me da los 5 valores que necesitaría, pero obviamente recorta cuando
> se pone un espacio para continuar. El problema que no logro comprender
> es desde que puse la linea;

```
cin.getline(str[i], 60, '\n');
```

> > Aquí si recoge el string completo pero con ese problema que me recorta 1 número. En descendente no pude arreglarlo ya que si ponía -1
> > hacía cosas raras.

Comment: Quizás porque estás iniciando i en -1

Comment: No, es lo contrario, si inicio en 0 da 4 elementos, si inicio en -1 (que se no es correcto) da los 5 elementos.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Como puedes ver con el siguiente código, leer un número desde `cin` con el operador `>>` deja un salto de línea.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

int main(){
    int a;
    std::string s;

    std::cin >> a;
    std::cout << a << "\n";
    if (std::cin.peek() == '\n')
        std::cout <<  "Hay un salto\n";
    std::getline(std::cin, s);
    std::cout << s << "\n";
    if (std::cin.peek() == '\n')
        std::cout << "Hay un salto\n";
}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##pY67DsIwDEX3fIVVhjYSMKM@MvMRXUwaKovUrUg6IMS3hz5EK1Q2PFj29fHV1V130Ba5DmFHrG1fGcipdf5usFFi1QaFuFZCEHtokDiRTwFDjTtm0@h8laYzCC4Tq6aJQakvTLe9hzwHHFtUcjTf6ArJ5@XYGXNLJBQFxCXHcgI2BhCd8QE9g0Pr28VoYmrjLbFZHPfg5I8M7t8M2wivEE4CL1q8AQ)

Lo más probable es que te suceda lo mismo.

Para quitarte ese salto de línea de en medio solo tienes que llamar a `cin.ignore()`.