# No permite almacenar un dato al ejecutar el programa

Tags: c++

cuando ejecuto el programa, el compilador de visual studio 2022, lee la línea donde se pide el nombre pero inmediatamente se salta a la línea donde se pide la edad, no permitiendo ingresar el nombre.

```
struct corredor {

    int edad;
    char nombre[20];
    char sexo[20];
    char club[20];
    
}corredor1;

int main(){
    int cantidad;

    cout << " cuantos alumnos va a ingresar: ";
    cin >> cantidad;

    for (int i = 0; i < cantidad; i++) {
        cout << "\ningrese el nombre del alumno " << i + 1 << ": " << endl;
        cin.getline(alumno1[i].nombre1,20,'\n');
        cout << "ingrese la edad: ";
        cin>> alumno1[i].edad1;
        cout << "ingrese el promedio de las notas: ";
        cin >> alumno1[i].promedio;

        cout << "\n";
    }

    cout << "has finalizado de ingresar los datos";
}
```

Comment: Cuando lees números con el operador `>>`, deja un salto de línea sin leer. Necesitas quitarlo. Posible duplicado: [¿Por qué si pido 5 valores, solo me imprime 4 con getline?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/q/529554/169744). Más info: https://es.stackoverflow.com/q/193829/169744

Comment: Por cierto, no es el compilador el que no lee la línea. Es el programa. Como sugerencia, nunca está demás inicializar las variables (lo digo por la variable `cantidad` y no recuerdo si los struct también).

Comment: Mil gracias por la respuesta, lo pondré en practica.