# "Error" cin.get en c++

Tags: c++, vectores

Estoy haciendo practicas de código y me he topado con un problema usando `cin.get`, estuve investigando su uso en diversas paginas pero no encuentro ningun error, y encima el compilador de CLion no da ningun error significativo, aquí dejo el codigo que puse:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main(){

    const int max = 100;
    char vector_inicial[max], vector_final[max], vector_sustitucion[max];
    char sustitucion;

    cout<<"Dame los valores de tipo char para la cadena y pon un # para finalizarla: ";
    cin.get(vector_inicial, 100);

    cout<<"Dame el char que deseas sustituir: ";
    cin>>sustitucion;

    cout<<"Ahora dame los char que quieres sustituir por "<<sustitucion<<" en la misma linea de escritura: "<<endl;
    cin.get(vector_sustitucion, 100);

    if(vector_sustitucion[0] != NULL) {
        for (int i; vector_inicial[i] != '#'; i++) {
            if (sustitucion != vector_inicial[i]) {
                cout << vector_inicial[i];
            } else if (sustitucion == vector_inicial[i]) {
                //Bucle en el que se recorre el vector que se va a sustituir//
                for (int N_actual; N_actual != max; N_actual++) {
                    cout << vector_sustitucion[N_actual];
                }
            }
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

El problema que veo es que el segundo `cin.get` que coloco no se compila correctamente, si compilo y voy escribiendo sale esto:

```
Dame los valores de tipo char para la cadena y pon un # para finalizarla:a b c A B C a b c#
 Dame el char que deseas sustituir:a
 Ahora dame
los char que quieres sustituir por a en la misma linea de escritura:

Process finished with exit code 0
```

Comment: La comparación `vector_sustitucion[0] != NULL` no tiene mucho sentido, qué quieres lograr con eso?

Comment: Está pregunta está duplicadisima. Lo que sucede es que `cin >>` no consume el salto de línea que ingresas. Aquí encontré una publicación donde se responde [¿Por qué si pido 5 valores, solo me imprime 4 con getline?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/529554/por-qu%c3%a9-si-pido-5-valores-solo-me-imprime-4-con-getline)

Comment: El `vector_sustitución[0] != NULL` es para comprobar si el error estaba en el bucle o en los `cin.get()`, solo hace eso

Comment: y no comprendo la publicación adjunta esa, no se que es lo que la relaciona a la mía

Comment: NULL o mejor, `nullptr`, debería usarse solo con punteros. Comparar con `NULL` equivale a comparar con 0.

Answer (score 0):

Cuando le das entrada al programa tienes que presionar ENTER. Ese salto de línea también va al buffer de `cin`.

La línea

```
cin >> sustitucion;
```

Solo consume el primer carácter que hayas introducido. [Ignorando los espacios o saltos de línea que se encuentren antes](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_istream/operator_gtgt).

El problema está en que la sobrecarga de `get` que estás usando solo lee hasta que encuentra un salto de línea. Si no te resulta evidente, puedes comprobarlo [aquí](https://tio.run/##bZJPb9swDMXv/hSEc2gCpEV3XdQARXdYzwN2WYaBk5mEqEy5klzsD/bZMyqKU7upDzqQ1Ht8P9l23fXO2sNhxmJd3xAY9jEFwnZd9ZFlB4ItxQ4tQUzNqqpYErTIMl/8rSrQz3qJCUr5F9zBh9vbVWnsMcAL2eTDDxa2jO6bjnxfDsUty9tS7GPi1Fv2cmyMlEat1eDcJ2PqT7ohOB/hBZ0PFEFjJO58udZhQHAIFhsShN/QeYFeYFY6xx34DwaHH6E@2bHc7CjNp7svc7LFO9bkitNzT2odCeOwK4ex5no9iZCrxyOjs3sll307oqf5YnU2AWOg3siD7moTBSBR3ilg41U6N@2@DPMW5lnlDq42crU41iYiS1A0GjyiSz4zciyE9TTQRu73XrE0A9NzsueeKcM9R1OQAWpjRqFUQBfMtFuOLRaHbEXRBp0JmbExJI17l/RIaqD9hsPXx/IYp/DTF7qY/vKqd7pw8QJj7cvxy73KrUAaRkB/9H@Hw2fvcIY/bUPbCiv/Hw).

Más información en [la sobrecarga 3 de esta documentación](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_istream/get). Tampoco consume el delimitador, lee la sobrecarga 4 de la documentación. Quizá prefieras usar [`getline`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_istream/getline).

Cabe mencionar que en lugar de posteriormente hacer la comparación `vector_inicial[i] != '#'`, podrías usar:

```
cin.getline(vector_inicial, 100, '#');
```

---

Entonces, como en la pregunta que sugerí, necesitas consumir ese salto de línea. Puedes hacerlo mediante la función [`ignore`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_istream/ignore):

```
cin >> sustitucion;
cin.ignore(1); // ignora un caracter

// o ignora hasta encontrar un salto de línea inclusive
// cin.ignore(std::numeric_limits<std::streamsize)::max(), '\n');
```

---

Si lo que buscabas es una forma más simple de lectura, podes usar [`read`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_istream/ignore).