# Qué tiene de malo este codigo? C++ (Struct)

Tags: c++, struct

Un programa que almacene datos de hasta 100 canciones. Deberá tener un menú que permita las opciones: añadir una nueva canción, mostrar el título de todas las canciones, buscar la canción que contenga un cierto texto (en el artista o en el título).
No sé por qué pero al momento de compilar en i = 0, empieza con el rellenado del titulo, pero no me deja, se salta titulo y pasa a artista para continuar normalmente. ¿Por qué pasa esto?

```
struct canciones
    {
        char titulo[30];
        char artista[30];
        int orden_cancion;
        int duracion;
    };

#include <iostream>
#include <conio.h>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

int main(){
    
    int total_canciones;
    cout << "Total de canciones: "; cin >> total_canciones;
    struct canciones cancion[total_canciones];
    cout << ":::::::::::::::::::::::::" << endl << endl;
    
    for (int i = 0; i < total_canciones; i++){
        cancion[i].orden_cancion = i;
        cout << "Orden de la cancion " << i << endl;
        cout << "Titulo " << i << ": ";
        cin.getline(cancion[i].titulo, '\n');
        cout << "Artista " << i << ": ";
        cin.getline(cancion[i].artista, '\n');
        cout << "Duracion (Seg.) " << i << ": ";
        cin >> cancion[i].duracion;
        cout << "::::::::::::::::::::" << endl;
    }
    
    
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Nota: en C++ no necesitas escribir `struct` antes de declarar una variable. Por cierto, es buena práctica darle a las estructuras nombres en singular. Por ejemplo *canción* y que el arreglo se llame *canciones*.

Comment: Prueba agregando `cin.ignore();` debajo de `cin >> total_canciones;`

Comment: ¿Responde esto a tu pregunta? [¿Por qué si pido 5 valores, solo me imprime 4 con getline?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/529554/por-qu%c3%a9-si-pido-5-valores-solo-me-imprime-4-con-getline) o ["Error" cin.get en c++](https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/583472/169744)

Comment: @Cris223511.dev Me ha funcionado, muchas gracias a todos!

Comment: @Mateo también lo ha hecho, gracias :D